# save video from webcam on the user's computer through a website

Tags: jquery, html, flash, webcam

It's a static webpage and I want the user to be able to record a video of himself while surfing the page. so no need for sending the video to the server or streaming to anyone else.

The rest of the page is in html, so I'm hoping to find a simple API or piece of code to do the job.

[This](http://www.xarg.org/project/jquery-webcam-plugin/) is what I could find but it's more than what I need. It needs a server...

Note: This is to be run only on a few computer stations for some data gathering. So it doesn't have to run on different systems/no storage limits/etc.

Answer (score 6):

**Capturing video.**

I would suggest checking WebRTC API which allows to access video and audio streams in Chrome and Firefox browsers: https://github.com/addyosmani/getUserMedia.js

**Saving large files on client side**

File System API allows you to store large file on client size, limited only by amount of disk space available. Check out http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/

Comment: but as you said. it only works on chrome and firefox that too on the latest versions...